# How-to configure Dell Drac5 and access to it

Tags: dell, debian-squeeze, drac, dell-openmanage

Help me please how to configure Dell Drac5 and How to access to it. Tried almost everything on google and still no idea, how Drac works. Will I be able to reboot my machine even without VNC or SSH access?

I have installed OMSA 7.1 on my Debian and can configure Drac through my webinterface. Now there is default IP 192.168.0.120 and default subnetmask 255.255.255.0, gateway is 192.168.0.1 how should I set it? My server IP is: 94.142.233.X and mask 255.255.255.192 and how to access it then? [dunno if it helps, but having installed nginx webserver on the machine]

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate network connection for the DRAC. Without knowing the details about the network your server is on, I'll just leave it at that.

Plug in the cable to the DRAC interface (it's isolated from the rest of the network interfaces).  From OMSA, set the DRAC IP to dynamic and see which IP it gets.  Visit that IP in your browser. Default Dell DRAC login is root, password calvin.

That'll get you in, but you need to make sure you can get to it when needed. So you'll either need a static IP, or some way to set a hostname for the IP.

Comment: I was under the impression that DRAC was built into the NIC as opposed to being a dedicated network port like HP's iLO...although I am likely wrong.

Comment: It may be that some of the cheaper models do, but I've never seen one personally. In this pic: http://www.storagereview.com/images/StorageReview-Dell-PowerEdge-R720-Motherboard.jpg, you can see the DRAC interface clearly labeled on the left side.

Comment: @tombull89 DRAC Express (no remote console) is shared with NIC1. DRAC Enterprise (remote console and virtual media) is a dedicated daughter board.